# Win64OpenSSL-1_0_0 - where to find it?

Tags: openssl

OpenSSL 1.0.0 x64

Is version above available somewhere as an .exe installer, or it should be built somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use a vulnerable version of OpenSSL?  I strongly suggest you download the source for the current version and compile it yourself.

Comment: Also see Shining Light Production's [Win32 OpenSSL page](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Thomas pre-builds the library and utilities for you and packages them in a Windows installer.

Answer (score 2):

**OpenSSL for Windows**

Pre-compiled Win32/64 libraries without external dependencies to the Microsoft Visual Studio Runtime DLLs, except for the system provided msvcrt.dll. The file is distributed as an archive which contains an .exe installer file called openssl.exe.

The following link contains a list of files to download, including `openssl-1.0.0t-x64_86-win64.zip`: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

**Binaries - OpenSSLWiki**

Third-party OpenSSL related binary distributions: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries